# Rails: How to use a filter on an each statement:

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a html filter box which looks like this:

```
<label for="datefrom">Date From:</label>
      <input type="date" id="datefrom" class="form-control" name="date" value="dd/mm/yyyy">
      <label for="dateto">Date To:</label>
      <input type="date" id="dateto" class="form-control" name="date" value="dd/mm/yyyy">
      <hr>
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" checked name="optradio">All</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">opt1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">opt2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">opt3</label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">opt4</label>
      </div>

      <div style="float:right">
        <button class="btn btn-info" name="button">Apply Filters</button>
      </div>
```

Now I have an each statement that looks like this

```
<% @events.each do |event|%>
<div class='positive'>
    <div class='icon'></div>
    <div class='message'><%= event.eventname %></div>
    <div class='date'><%= event.date %> <%= event.time %></div>
    <%= link_to 'Compare', event_path(event.id), class: "button ok" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So the each returns around 200 events, What I want is for the date from and date  to be a range filter that will get every event inside a range of dates defined in the filter

So if 3 events have dates like

22/01/2016
23/01/2016
25/01/2016

And if the date range was submitted at 21/01/2016 to 23/01/2016 then the 22/01/2016 and the 23/01/2016 would show but the rest wouldn't.

Thanks for any help!

**Edit**

Heres the controller:

```
  def search
    @events = Event.page(params[:page]).per(10).search params[:search], suggest: true, misspellings: { distance: 1 }, order: { date: :asc, eventname: :asc }, match: :word_start
    if @events.results.any?
      render 'events/results'
    else
      render 'events/noresults'
    end
  end
```

Sam

Comment: please also share the controller action code snippet where `@event` variable is being set.

Comment: If you have your array of dates, like `dates = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` within the @events variable, instead of iterating over them with an `each` you could iterate over them by doing something like `ranges = [(1..3),(4..7),(8..10)]` and then `ranges.each { |range| dates.map { |n| n if range.include?(n) }.compact }`. Use those sub arrays to populate your from and to date in the template.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you'll get the `dateFrom` and the `dateTo` in the params.

From there, your can filter your events with something like so:

```
@events = Event.where(date: @date_from..@date_to)
```

You can then display your stuff as you do now in the views.

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to have the button as a submit url, Have the dates passed through on the url to params, And then to the same method above as params[:datefrom] ? Wouldn't i be better doing the same method but just under a different name? Because there wouldn't always be a date available on initial search?

Comment: Yes that would work. You could have your `events_controller#index` action that would accept the search parameters. If they are any, use them to filter the events you want to return, otherwise display some events (for instance, the most popular ones or the recent ones).

Comment: Hey, How would i do the above? Stuggling with it :(